# Gruntfile fails with Warning: Task "taskname" not found

Tags: gruntjs

This happens with whatever task I'm trying to run.
When running with `--verbose` flag I'm getting:

> Initializing Command-line options: --verbose
>
> Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK
>
> Registering Gruntfile tasks. Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
>
> > > No tasks were registered or unregistered.

This is the Gruntfile:

```js
module.export = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        karma_coveralls: {
            options: {
                coverage_dir: 'coverage'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ['app/js/**/*.js', 'Gruntfile.js'],
            options: grunt.file.readJSON('.jshintrc')
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                seperator: ';'
            },
            dist: {
                src: ['app/js/**/*.js'],
                dest: 'dist/app/js/<%pkg.name%>.js'
            }
        },
        exec: {
            instrument: {
                cmd: function () {
                    return 'istanbul instrument app/js -o app/instrumentjs';
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma-coveralls');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('coverage', ['coveralls']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);
    grunt.registerTask('instrument', ['exec: instrument']);
    grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);

};
```

Any Idea what am I doing wrong?

grunt versions:

grunt-cli v0.1.9
grunt v0.4.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your Gruntfile, `module.export` should be `module.exports`.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, but for me the culprit was the casing on my task names...  I was using pascal-case on my grunt options object, but it expects all lowercase (ex: I had cssMin, should be cssmin)

Comment: You were using camel case, not pascal case.

Comment: @badsyntax the solution didn't work for me. I even checked the case and its all correct. any other possibility why am I getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of /node modules while calling grunt.loadNpmTasks in Gruntfile.js